# drawing an image within specific bounds

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm working on some app and I came across a requirement to implement an checkbox-behaving imageview, when it's checked it's overlayed with this image:

[image: link to the image]

The edges of the image are transparent the image underneath is generated dynamically.

My problem is that I have no idea how to implement this, I tried putting two imageviews one over the other in a layout, and overriding imageview, but i can't figure out how to bound the underlying image inside the rectangle.

Comment: You can simply use **both** the `android:background` and the `android:src` attributes in your xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `setBounds` method? Just like: `imageview2.getDrawable().setBounds(imageView1.getLeft(), imageView1.getTop(), imageView1.getRight(), imageView1.getBottom())`